# Command line tools on Mavericks

Tags: command-line, osx-mavericks

As [many have pointed out](http://www.computersnyou.com/2025/) this should work, `xcode-select --install`

I however consistently get

[image]

I have XCODE `Version 5.0.1 (5A2053)` installed.

**What am i missing please and how can I get command line tools installed?**

Comment: Check if xcode is pulling from the right place using xcode-select -print-path. You should get /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer as a result